# download a SQL back up file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to download  sql back up file but getting error :
"Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack" near respone.end()

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string backupDestination = backupPath;
            string dbNAme = dbName;
            string dateStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd@HHmm");
            string backupfile = backupDestination + '\\' + dbNAme + " of " + dateStamp + ".bak";

            DataTable dt = blu.queryFunction("BACKUP database " + dbNAme + " to disk='" + backupDestination + "\\" + dbNAme + " of " + dateStamp + ".Bak'");

            WebClient req = new WebClient();
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.Buffer = true;

            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= " + dbNAme + ".bak");
            
            byte[] data = req.DownloadData(backupfile);
            response.ContentType = "application/sql";
            response.BinaryWrite(data);
            response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertscipt", "swal('Error!','Database Backup Failed." + ex.ToString() + "','warning')", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: string backupDestination = "C:\SQLBackUpFolder";
string dbNAme = "test";

Comment: Just a thought; have you tried running this without the try/catch, to make sure you don't happen to hide the original exception somehow?

Comment: @Culme i have tried that too, it doesn't show any error but the file is not being downloaded

Comment: Have you tried creating the backup file in advance, to test only the file download part of your code? It would seem likely that the backup file hasn't been fully created at the time when you try to transfer it.

Comment: @Culme i checked the backup was already done before trying  to download and i tried like u said still the same error occurs

Comment: But wait... Is the backup stored on another server, or why are you using a WebClient to fetch it? If "backupfile" is just a regular file path, you should be able to use Respose.WriteFile(backupfile) or similar to get to the content.

Comment: @Culme the system is hosted on server and i am trying to download it from client Pc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238501/discussion-between-culme-and-cks).

Comment: @cks Try : BACKUP DATABASE [YourDB] TO  DISK = N'X:\YourBackUpPath\YourBackUpName.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'YourDB-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10

Comment: @zambee same error.

Answer (score 1):

One issue that I see is the buffer - change the `response.Buffer = true;` to false

```
response.Buffer = false;
```

for big files this is wrong because its put it on a buffer but you want to send it direct to the user...

also remove the `catch (Exception ex)` to see other problems on your code - the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` is not run from the moment you have change the headers. So the issue is hidden from you.

One other better and more correct way is to create a handler and download the file from there.

Answer (score 0):

If the backup file is present on the server running the application, you shouldn't be using a WebClient. Something that reads the file from local disk, e.g. TransmitFile(), would then be sufficient - like this:

```
string backupDestination = backupPath;
string dbNAme = dbName;
string dateStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd@HHmm");
string backupfile = backupDestination + '\\' + dbNAme + " of " + dateStamp + ".bak";

DataTable dt = blu.queryFunction("BACKUP database " + dbNAme + " to disk='" + backupDestination + "\\" + dbNAme + " of " + dateStamp + ".Bak'");

HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

response.Clear();
response.ClearContent();
response.ClearHeaders();
response.Buffer = true;

response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= " + dbNAme + ".bak");

response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
response.TransmitFile(backupfile);
response.Flush();
```

Comment: the code runs but file is not being downloaded

Comment: Weird...
What if you do both Response.Flush() and then Response.End()?
Do you get any response at all back from the server, or what happens when you click the button?

Answer (score 0):

ok so after 72 hours i have found the error. the download button was inside update panel so i was getting "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack"

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string dbNAme = dbName;
            string backupDestination = Server.MapPath("~/BackUp");
            string dateStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd@HH_mm");
            string fileName = dbName + " of " + dateStamp + ".Bak";

            if (!Directory.Exists(backupDestination))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(backupDestination);
            }

            DataTable dt = blu.queryFunction("BACKUP database " + dbNAme + " to disk='" + backupDestination + "\\" + fileName + "'");


            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(backupDestination, fileName));
            // Delete .bak file from server folder.
            if (Directory.Exists(backupDestination))
            {
                Directory.Delete(backupDestination, true);
            }
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string exception = ex.ToString();
        }            
    }
```